# Is the runtime complexity of my code O(a+b)?

Tags: python

I just solved this problem on LeetCode. Its quite simple but im not sure about the runtime complexity of the code. can anyone explain it to me.

```
def addBinary(self, a: str, b: str) -> str:
        carry = 0
        result = ''

        a = list(a)
        b = list(b)

        while a or b or carry:
            if a:
                carry += int(a.pop())
            if b:
                carry += int(b.pop())

            result += str(carry %2)
            carry //= 2

        return result[::-1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop will run until there is nothing in a, or in b, and the carry is 0.
Each time you iterate, you reduce the number of entries in a and b by one. Therefore, the Total number of iterations is `max(len(a),len(b)) +x` where `x` is 1 if there is something left in carry at the end, and 0 otherwise Since x is basically bounded by a constant (the constant 1) you can ignore it for the asymptotic part.

Note that `(len(a)+len(b))/2<=max(len(a),len(b))<=len(a)+len(b)` so

max(len(a),len(b))+1 is O(len(a)+ len(b))

and len(a)+len(b) is O( max(len(a),len(b)))

Comment: I got downvoted. I know just wanna know if my question is bad? like the content is bad or the way I ask?

Comment: I'm not sure, but my guess is that it has a "homework" flavor. It might help if you add context, e.g. explain what part of the complexity calculation you were struggling with.

Comment: Oh. I just started using stackoverflow i dont  really know much about it. but I just wanna know the time complexity its nothing about homework. like i said I solved it on leetcode. but I just didnt know the big O

Answer (score 1):

No, it's `O(max(len(a), len(b))`. Each iteration of the `while` loop processes one element of `a` and `b`. Even when it has reached the end of the shorter string, it has to perform the `if` test for that string each time it processes an element of the longer string. And the last two statements in the loop are executed either way.

For purpose of calculating complexity, we ignore the fact that it executes one less statement in each iteration when it reaches the end of the shorter string.

Comment: O(max(len(a),len(b)) is the same as O(len(a)+len(b))

Comment: I suppose. Either way, it's linear.

Answer (score 1):

Here the worst time complexity can be `O(max(len(a),len(b)))`

**Explanation**:

Let a = '11111111' and b = '11'

The while loop will iterate till both of list a and list b are empty and carry equals 0, in our example b will be empty after 2nd iteration, but still the while loop will continue till list a becomes empty, for len(max(a,b)) times i.e. len(a) = 8 iterations and even after that it will iterate one more time to add carry (while could have been moved out of the loop)

The solution can be improvised. Hint: Change the while condition to loop for min(len(a),len(b))). I will leave it to you for further implementaion